# Terraform : Tagging ALL google compute INSTANCES at once using Terraform

Tags: terraform, tagging, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I have an existing project with instances running in the project. I have authenticated in the project using Terraform and credentials file. I am suppose to get existing resource by inputing the project ID.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("${var.path}/terraform-ma.json")}"

  project = "terraform-ma-2020"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-b"
}



data "google_project" "project" {
}

output "project_id" {
  value = data.google_project.project.project_id

}
```

Comment: How does the AWS provider do that for you? What would you do with the AWS provider to achieve this? Can you edit your question to include that as an [mcve] and explain how that doesn't work for the GCP provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can import existing GCP resources into Terraform state files using the information found in https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html

Comment: Is it necessary to import all the resources using Terraform import command? Terraform says that you can fetch data once you have ACCESS to anything. My only confusion is by authenticating into the project through credentials file using Terraform we do have access to the project. But in order to fetch data our tfstate file should be updated with the present/existing infrastructure right and that the data block can fetch the data from tfstate file. Is this why importing is important???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can use Terraform to create resources from .tf files. Importing the existing resources will only create the .tfstate file, not the. .tf files. So you'd have to work with the state file to create the configuration files.

Comment: I will try to reframe my question. In short if the infrastructure isn't created through Terraform then IMPORT is absolutely necessary in order to manage and update the existing infrastructure, right?
Data source block is used to fetch information from the resources you have access to. If I have access to the project through service key account credentials. Does that mean we can retrieve the information of the resources under that project without using the IMPORT command?? Or for Data source command to work you need to have the .tfstate file upto date with your exisitng infrastructure?

Comment: You can import existing infrastructure created manually: yes. But not all resources types support import if I remember correctly.